# Trying to write a HASH TABLE in C, am I doing the right thing here?

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

So I have a hash function already given to me.

I have an object struct of:

```
OBJKT 
{
   OBJKT *o_hash_next;
   OBJKT *o_hash_prev;
   ... bunch of other stuff
}
```

I also have the hash array declared in the header file: OBJKT *hash_tbl[hsize];

The method that is supposed to add a given OBJKT to the hash takes in a hash key, and the OBJKT we are adding.

So this is what I am not sure I am doing correctly:

```
void insert_in_hash(int hashindex, OBJKT *thisObject)
{
   *thisObject->o_hash_next = *hash_tbl[hashindex];
   *hash_tbl[hashindex]->o_hash_prev=*thisObject;
   *hash_tbl[hashindex] = *thisObject;
}
```

Does this seem correct? I am trying to set the previous/next pointers and then add the thisObject into the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks about right.  For a hashtable you don't necessarily need a doubly-linked list, though.

Don't forget to zero your hash_tbl to start.

And you may find it useful to have the hashvalue directly in your OBJKT entries, to speed searches.

### Update

Based on unexplored's comments (those darn "*" characters), it probably should look like this:

```
void insert_in_hash(int hashindex, OBJKT *thisObject)
{
   thisObject->o_hash_next = hash_tbl[hashindex];
   thisObject->o_hash_prev = NULL;
   hash_tbl[hashindex]->o_hash_prev=thisObject;
   hash_tbl[hashindex] = thisObject;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by double linked?

Comment: Doubly-linked means with both forward and reverse pointers.  For a simple hashtable (especially if you will only insert, never remove) you only need forward links.  Even if you remove, the back links are not necessary, just sometimes convenient.

Comment: Ah alright. Well yeah I don't think I would need them but my professor had them in the pseudo code. We are implementing a cache simulator the cache is basically represented by this table. Thanks for the help btw!

Answer (score 0):

It's late and I am a bit tired, but what i see is extra dereferencing.

First: `OBJKT *hash_tbl[]` is already an array of pointers to linked lists.
So when you need the head of the list you just use `hash_tbl[index]`, that will give you a pointer which has to be assigned to you `thisObject->o_hash_next` which is a pointer too. DON'T dereference. What you have `*thisObject->o_hash_next = *hash_tbl[hashindex]` is copying the **value** from one address to another address, and this is not what you want I am assuming. Same thing applies for the previous pointer.

Your solution might look as following:

```
void insert_in_hash(int hashindex, OBJKT *thisObject)
{
    thisObject->o_hash_next          = hash_tbl[hashindex];
    hash_tbl[hashindex]->o_hash_prev = thisObject;
    thisObject->o_hash_prev          = NULL; // Don't forget to NULL if not in use
}
```

The last line was removed as this is not how you usually keep track of the head of the list.

Anyway, as I said, it's late and I didn't have time to test my code but here is a usefull link to a linked list tutorial: [C/C++ Linked List tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/linked_list.aspx)

**Edit**

You should keep the head of the list as you did in your code: `hash_tbl[hashindex] = thisObject`. See comments bellow

Comment: Yep, I always kind of skip over seeing the "*" in C code, so I missed the double indirections.  But I don't see why you removed assigning thisObject to hash_tbl[hashindex], since I don't see any other way to keep track of the head of the list.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks & @antonpug Yep, Daniel was right. As I said It was late, and I kind of forgot that this is an array and that `hashindex` will refer to the head. In a regular list I would have another variable `OBJKT* head` which will always have to be readjusted everytime you insert at the head of the list. And since this a double linked list, perhaps a tail pointer will be useful too.

Comment: I'd avoid the tail pointer, unless it's absolutely necessary.  They cause no end of trouble.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I agree with you in the case of a hash table as you always start from HEAD (at least in my experience), but if this list is double linked and is not in a hash than it makes sense to traverse it backwards and starting from end in some cases my speed things up

Comment: It's just that managing a tail pointer is tricky.  I screw it up about half the time.  You don't have bugs in code you don't write.